# Testing Postgre Database on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, mocha.js

I am currently building an API with Swagger on Heroku and i would like to try if the endpoints are creating the correct entries in the Postgre Database. However, once i try to connect to Heroku's Postgre in my testing envoirment the connection is rejected. I think this is because in the continous integration envoirnment heroku creates a sandbox and does not accept connections to the real dbs.

I tried to create a backup database as suggested here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups
but i couldn't find the information to access!

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Here is my code test:

```
'use strict';

var should = require('should');
var request = require('supertest');
var assert = require('assert');
var server = require('../../../app');

var pg = require('pg');
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL

});

describe('controllers', function () {
  describe('testing cenas', function () {
     it('test1', function (done) {

      request(server)
        .get('/hello')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {

          assert.equal(res.body, 'Hello,Hugo Pereira!');
          done();
        });
    });


  });
});
```

it gives an error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unable to acquire a connection
    at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:332:40)
    at Runner.ensureConnection (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:233:24)
    at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:47:42)
    at Builder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:39:43)
    at testPg (/app/api/controllers/hello_world.js:27:44)
    at swaggerRouter (/app/node_modules/swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-router.js:407:20)
    at swagger_router (/app/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/fittings/swagger_router.js:31:5)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bagpipes/lib/bagpipes.js:171:7)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at Runner.runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at Runner.pipeline (/app/node_modules/pipeworks/pipeworks.js:72:17)
    at Runner.flow (/app/node_modules/pipeworks/pipeworks.js:223:19)
    at Pipeworks.flow (/app/node_modules/pipeworks/pipeworks.js:135:17)
    at Pipeworks.siphon (/app/node_modules/pipeworks/pipeworks.js:186:19)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/bagpipes/lib/bagpipes.js:98:22)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
  0 passing (2s)
```

Comment: it turns out it was my error you need to define your process.env.DATABASE_URL in your testing envoirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve this problem using the heroku in-dyno database (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-in-dyno-databases). Once i got the database I go to a endpoint in my dev env that i made myself that gives me a dump file of the schemas of my real db. In the test env i import this file and voila i have all the schemas and tables i need for my test envoirment.

Answer (score 0):

The [`heroku pg:psql`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql) command should connect to your database. You can also pass it parameters to connect to alternative/backup databases.

Comment: They have documentation about it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a heroku postgres url then one thing you need for external access is the query string `?ssl=true` appended to the url

e.g.

```
"DATABASE_URL" : "postgres://user:pass@ec2-54-235-206-118.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbid?ssl=true"
```